# CPU temps reach 90+ *C while compiling OpenCV

Tags: compiling, intel, cpu, temperature, opencv

So I got a used workstation specifically a Lenovo D20.

It's configuration is:

2x Xeon X5670 (stock speed and cooler)

16 GB Registered ECC (4x 4GB)

300GB VelociRaptor 10k RPM HDD

Nvidia Quadro 600

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

While I was compiling OpenCV from source I saw that the Cpu temps from a number of cores were reaching well above 90* C. What could be the issue? All other temps were kinda normal around 45 - 60 *C. Only the core temps used to go that high and then after remaining there for say 4 -5 mins drop to 50 - 60 *C. After that they again climbed up and went down again, till the compilation was done.

I was measuring temps using psensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step #1:**

Blow out any dust from your computer, especially from the fans and CPU cooler. If your computer is older, thermal paste on the CPU's may need re-application.

**Step #2:**

I'd install `thermald`...

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install thermald

`Thermald` was buggy in early versions of 16.04. Update to 16.04.2 and it should be ok.

`Thermald` comes with a default configuration file at `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` that will control most computers, but may need to be customized for some computers. See `man thermal-conf.xml` for some details and examples. Once one has modified the configuration file, stop `thermald` and restart it:

```
sudo service thermald restart
```

After installing thermald, I'd stop the `thermald` process, and run it manually as `sudo thermald --no-daemon` to watch its actions in real time. This real time info can be used to create your own customized thermal-conf.xml file. See `man thermald` for more information.

```
sudo service thermald stop
sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
```

You can search for `thermald` here on Ask Ubuntu to see what previous answers there are.

A good starter reference is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Comment: Okay so it turns out my fans were dirty and the thermal paste was virtually non existent. Cleaned up the fans and applied new thermal solution.

Idle Temps: 30*C
Full Load Temps: 60-70*C

Comment: @Senpaivg Good news! Glad it's working good now.